Suppress vscode's "Waiting for preLaunchTask" popup
Since I upgraded to the latest vscode (1.93.0) and vscode-csharp extension (2.45.20), when I run a task involving compilation a small popup appears in the lower right with:
Waiting for preLaunchTask 'foo'...

    [Debug Anyway] [Configure Task] [Abort]

Compilation take a long time, hence that popup.
I find it distracting and useless, how can I hide it?

Looking at the source code at the time of this writing, I don't think you can. I don't see any related setting check. You could raise a feature-request issue ticket asking for there to be a setting to ignore this, or a "don't ask me again" option.
An issue ticket was raised at Option to disable 'Waiting for preLaunchTask' popup #228640. It should be addressed in the October 2024 release, courtesy of PR 228640: Hiding prelaunch task popup if the setting to hide it is enabled #231225. Use the debug.hideSlowPreLaunchWarning setting.
